# How to map to "this" with AutoMapper in constructor

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-2, automapper-3

I have a source type which have properties and a destination type which have exactly the same properties.

After I configure one simple mapping for AutoMapper like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MySourceType, MyDestinationType>();
```

I would like to have a constructor of MyDestinationType which have a MySourceType
parameter, then automatically initialize properties of the type under creation with the source like this:

```
public MyDestinationType(MySourceType source)
{
    // Now here I am do not know what to write.
}
```

The only workaround I found is create a static factory method for

```
public static MyDestinationType Create(MySourceType source)
{
     return Mapper.Map<MyDestinationType>(source);
}
```

Is there any way to not to have this static ugliness?

Comment: Why build a constructor? You want to be able to call `MyDestinationType destinationobj = new MyDestinationType(sourceobj);` but this would do the same as simply calling `MyDestinationType destinationobj = Mapper.Map<MyDestinationType>(sourceobj);`

If you really need a seperate constructor you could TRY `this = Mapper.Map<MyDestinationType>(source);` but I'm not 100% sure if you can do a direct assignment to `this`.

Edit: I tested it and you can't assign to `this`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although I personally find it ugly, what you can do is the following:

```
public MyDestinationType(MySourceType source)
{
    Mapper.Map<MySourceType, MyDestinationType>(source, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using:

```
public MyDestinationType(MySourceType source)
{
    var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<MySourceType, MyDestinationType>();
    });

    var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();

    mapper.Map(source, this);
}
```